# Delete String Within Quotation Marks

Tags: regex

I have a xml file with these datas:

```
PONumber="HC01/1501/000001"
PONumber="HC01/1501/000002"
PONumber="HC01/1501/000003"
PONumber="HC01/1501/000004"
...
PONumber="HC01/1501/000100"
```

What i want is to delete 'HC01/1501/000001' until 'HC01/1501/000100'.
How to do it using regular expression to replace them with empty string

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below regex would replace chars present present with double quotes with an empty string.

**Regex:**

```
"[^"]*"
```

- `"` - matches double quotes.
- `[^"]*` - negated character class which matches any character but not of double quotes, zero or more times.
- `"`- Matches the ending double quote.

So this matches a complete double quoted block. So by replacing the matched double quoted block with `""` will give you the expected output.

**Replacement string:**

```
""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=").*?(?=")
```

You can use `lookaheads` here.See demo.Replace by `empty string`

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/85

Answer (score 0):

For each line you can replace the matches string of following regex

```
(?<==).*
```

With `''`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oM2hW1/1)

`(?<=)` is a [positive look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and `(?<==).*` will match every thing after `=`.

Answer (score 0):

If thats only the data that you have, use the RegEx `/".*"/` and replacement as `""`.

[Demo & Explanation](https://www.regex101.com/r/lQ9hO5/1)

Else, use this RegEx: `/"HC01\/1501\/000(0[0-9][0-9]|100)"/g`

and the replacement string as `""`.

[Demo & Explanation](https://www.regex101.com/r/lQ9hO5/3)